# Volume generation by revolution

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region in the first quadrant enclosed by the curves $y = 6 − x$, $y = x^2$, $x = 0$ about $y = −3$.

[image]

Can someone help me to set up integral for this? Height can be visualized easily but I am confused as far as radius and limits of integrations are concerned.

Comment: Shift everything (all the functions) up 3 units. Now you are rotating around the $x$ axis.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Still can't identify radius.